# Conduct rolling sum and then assigning unique group names in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to assign unique group names to a data set based on a rolling sum. The example `DATA` table should illustrate my problem and see `RESULT` table for desired result.

The `DATA` table has two `Rivers`, each row is a sampling location along each `River`. I need to calculate a rolling sum for `Km_inbetween`and when that rolling sum exceeds 50, assign a group name to those rows. Then, repeat the process starting the rolling sum with the next row down.

In the `RESULTS` table for example, the first four rows for the `Ohio River` sum to greater than 50 and were assigned `Group 1`. However, the rolling sum of the next two rows exceed 50 and were assigned `Group 2`. Note that `GROUP` names start over for the `Missouri River`.

Solutions that use `dplyr` are preferred, but all suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance for your time.

`DATA` table:

```
Rivers  Km_inbetween
Ohio        6
Ohio        7
Ohio        34
Ohio        17
Ohio        47
Ohio        5
Ohio        5
Ohio        3
Ohio        5
Ohio        19
Ohio        11
Ohio        12
Missouri    11
Missouri    10
Missouri    34
Missouri    19
Missouri    5
Missouri    19
Missouri    19
```

`RESULTS` table:

```
Rivers  Km_inbetween    Group
Ohio         6            1
Ohio         7            1
Ohio         34           1
Ohio         17           1
Ohio         47           2
Ohio         5            2
Ohio         5            3
Ohio         3            3
Ohio         5            3
Ohio         19           3
Ohio         11           3
Ohio         12           3
Missouri     11           1
Missouri     10           1
Missouri     34           1
Missouri     19           2
Missouri     5            2
Missouri     19           2
Missouri     19           2
```

Comment: could you put `dput` or at very least format your data properly. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that @discipulus.....I posted this in hast. See edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this approach comes close to what you want.

It uses `dplyr` to `group_by` `Rivers`, calculates the `cumsum()` for each river and defines the groups by using `cut()` on the rolling sum.

```
data <- data.frame(Rivers = c(rep("Ohio", 12), rep("Missouri", 7)), Km_inbetween = c(6,7,34,17,47,5,5,3,5,19,11,12,11,10,34,19,5,19,19))

data %>% 
  group_by(Rivers) %>%
  mutate(cs = cumsum(Km_inbetween)) %>%
  mutate(group = cut(cs, breaks = c(0,50,100,150,200), labels = c(1,2,3,4))) %>%
  mutate(group = as.numeric(as.character(group)))
```

This results in:

```
     Rivers Km_inbetween    cs group
     <fctr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      Ohio            6     6     1
2      Ohio            7    13     1
3      Ohio           34    47     1
4      Ohio           17    64     2
5      Ohio           47   111     3
6      Ohio            5   116     3
7      Ohio            5   121     3
8      Ohio            3   124     3
9      Ohio            5   129     3
10     Ohio           19   148     3
11     Ohio           11   159     4
12     Ohio           12   171     4
13 Missouri           11    11     1
14 Missouri           10    21     1
15 Missouri           34    55     2
16 Missouri           19    74     2
17 Missouri            5    79     2
18 Missouri           19    98     2
19 Missouri           19   117     3
```